# How to filter a value of nested key of json

Tags: sql, arrays, json, postgresql

I have a table in PostgreSQL

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS account_details
(
    account_id integer,
    condition json
);
```

And the data's present inside this table are

| account_id | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[35,20,5,6]}}}] |
| 2 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[1,4,2,3,6]}}}] |
| 3 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[5]}}}] |

I need to fetch the details of all account having **rootcompanyid** in (5). IF part of any **rootcompanyid's ** are present in any of the account details should display the result.
So output should contain **account_id --> 1 and 3** rows

The below query is fetching only the last row (account_id = 3) not the first row

```
SELECT *
  FROM account_details
 WHERE ((condition->0->>'conditions')::json->>'rootcompanyid')::json->>'$in' = '[5]';
```

**Expected Output** : IF part of any **rootcompanyid's ** are present in any of the account details should display the result.

| account_id | condition |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[35,20,5,6]}}}] |
| 3 | [{"action":"read","subject":"rootcompany","conditions":{"rootcompanyid":{"$in":[5]}}}] |

Comment: What if your array contains more than one object? Do you want only rows where all array elements contain that ID or those where at least one array element contains the ID

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name It should check for more than one object also. So I want at least one array element contains the ID in each and every rows

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easily done with the JSON containment operator:

```
WHERE condition::jsonb @> '[ { "conditions": { "rootcompanyid": { "$in": [5] } } } ]'
```

If you want to search for more than a single array element, either use two of the above conditions with `OR` or use a JSONPATH query:

```
WHERE jsonb_path_exists(
         condition::jsonb,
         '$[*].conditions.rootcompanyid.\$in[*] ? (@ == 5 || @ == 6)'
      )
```

Comment: Hi @Laurenz Albe I tried with above query, but it didn't fetch any results.

 
 Select * from account_details
 WHERE condition ::jsonb @> '{ "conditions": { "rootcompanyid": { "$in": [5] } } }'. Can you please provide entire query ?

Comment: I forgot one array. Try again.

Comment: That really helped one of my scenario. But the query -------> WHERE condition::jsonb @> '[ { "conditions": { "rootcompanyid": { "$in": [**4,6**] } } } ]' ---->Is giving only one row ( **i.e account_id =2** ) instead of 2 rows (**i.e account_id 1 and 2**) This is because it is checking combination of 5 and 6 in each an every rows but not 5 or 6 alone in each and every rows. Is there any possibilities to search values based on OR condition in PostgreSQL??